# how to calculate middle points on circular arc draw using UIBezierPath path ios or swift

Tags: ios, swift

i'm drawing arc using UIBezierPath. how can i calculate middle point of this arc.

```
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2)
var startValue: CGFloat = 0
var startAngle: CGFloat = 0
var endValue: CGFloat = 0
var endAngle: CGFloat = 0

startAngle = (startValue * 2 * CGFloat(M_PI)) - CGFloat(M_PI_2)
endValue = startValue + 0.20
endAngle = (endValue * 2 * CGFloat(M_PI)) -CGFloat(M_PI_2)

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(center)
path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius.outer, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

path.fill()
path.stroke()
```

Answer (score 5):

The midPoint angle will be the average of your `startAngle` and your `endAngle`.  This calculates the point based upon the `center` point and the `radius.outer`:

```
let midPointAngle = (startAngle + endAngle) / 2.0
let midPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius.outer * cos(midPointAngle), y: center.y - radius.outer * sin(midPointAngle))
```

Comment: I have two points left and right , and by adding some value to Y (EASY) and X is  AVG of both left and right. I create 3rd point (Like V shape) After that I draw curve using bezier path between them And all works fine but Now I want to create two more points (5 Points curve) , One Between center and left and one between center and right . If i again get AVG it is not smooth . Could you PLEASE help me ...

Comment: @MikeAlter, Post a new question showing your code and the result you are getting and explain what result you were hoping to get.